# How to pass arguments to Celery task with Flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, redis, celery

Having trouble figuring out how to pass arguments to a Celery task. From what I read, I should be able to pass args=[arg1,arg2] but I keep getting this error:

`long_task() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Here is the `long_task()` function

```
@celery.task(bind=True)
def long_task(self, file_list):
    print(file_list)
    """Background task that runs a long function with progress reports."""
    verb = ['Starting up', 'Booting', 'Repairing', 'Loading', 'Checking']
    adjective = ['master', 'radiant', 'silent', 'harmonic', 'fast']
    noun = ['solar array', 'particle reshaper', 'cosmic ray', 'orbiter', 'bit']
    message = ''
    total = random.randint(10, 50)
    for i in range(total):
        if not message or random.random() < 0.25:
            message = '{0} {1} {2}...'.format(random.choice(verb),
                                              random.choice(adjective),
                                              random.choice(noun))
        self.update_state(state='PROGRESS',
                          meta={'current': i, 'total': total,
                                'status': message})
        time.sleep(1)
    return {'current': 100, 'total': 100, 'status': 'Task completed!',
            'result': 42}
```

and here is where I'm attempting to pass `file_list` argument to the `long_task()` function with apply_sync -
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async

```
@app.route('/longtask', methods=['POST'])
def longtask():
    file_list = ["file1", "file2"]
    task = long_task.apply_async(args=[file_list])
    return jsonify({}), 202, {'Location': url_for('taskstatus',
                                                  task_id=task.id)}
```

I've tried several different things, including using kwargs and also using `delay` instead of `apply_async` .

I'm following this guide - https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve it by restarting the Celery worker. Not sure exactly how it all works, but it seems that when the Celery worker gets started, it loads in information from app.py. If things change in app.py the Celery worker needs to reload as well. Just a hunch, if I'm incorrect please let me know!

Comment: You're correct. Celery doesn't auto-reload.